# How to connect to internet & load html using python/urllib in ubuntu?

Tags: python, urllib

I am new to programming, i had some problem with the code..
Here i  have posted the code below.
Actually after running the program its shows some error...

ERROR:
It shows some traceback error

```
import urllib
proxies = {'http' : 'http://proxy:80'}
urlopener = urllib.FancyURLopener(proxies)
htmlpage = urlopener.open('http://www.google.com')
data = htmlpage.readlines()
print data
```

Comment: Including the traceback error would be helpful. It allows you to trace the error. Back. Through your code.

Comment: Please edit your question.  Please read the formatting hints on the right side of the page.  Please format your code to look like code.

Answer (score 1):

You need indent your python and replace readlines() with read()

```
import urllib 
proxies = {'http' : 'http://proxy:80'} 
urlopener = urllib.FancyURLopener(proxies) 
htmlpage = urlopener.open('http://www.google.com') 
data = htmlpage.read() 
print data
```